# how to convert 'this' in "Self Referencing Generics"

Tags: c#, generics, delegates

I want to add an observer in my model, i try to generic delegate but here is problem when invoke.

Here is my code and it works when I use 'handler.DynamicInvoke(this)' instead of 'Invoke'

but I know DynamicInvoke is slow... I want to know is here a right way to use Invoke.

```
public class Model<T>
{
    public delegate void UpdatePrototype<T>(T mdl);

    private List<UpdatePrototype<T>> listeners = new List<UpdatePrototype<T>>();
    public void Bind(UpdatePrototype<T> handler)
    {
        listeners.Add(handler);
    }

    public void Sync()
    {
        foreach(UpdatePrototype<T> handler in listeners)
        {
            handler.Invoke((T)this); // << ERROR: can not convert Model<T> to T
        }
    }

    public string Name = "Model";
}

public class MyModel : Model<MyModel>
{
    public string Name = "MyModel";
}

public class YourModel : Model<YourModel>
{
    public string Name = "YourModel";
}

void Main()
{
    MyModel mdl = new MyModel();
    mdl.Bind(MyUpdate);
    mdl.Sync();

    YourModel your = new YourModel();
    your.Bind(YourUpdate);
    your.Sync();
}

void MyUpdate(MyModel mdl)
{
    Debug.Log(mdl.Name);
}

void YourUpdate(YourModel mdl)
{
    Debug.Log(mdl.Name);
}
```

＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝

thanks @IVAAAN123 i modify my code as follow.

it is fine for me, although `mdl.Sync<MyModel>()` has a little odd ;)

```
public class Model<T>
{
    public delegate void UpdatePrototype<T>(T mdl);

    private List<UpdatePrototype<T>> listeners = new List<UpdatePrototype<T>>();
    public void Bind(UpdatePrototype<T> handler)
    {
        listeners.Add(handler);
    }

    public void Sync()
    {
        foreach(UpdatePrototype<T> handler in listeners)
        {
            handler.DynamicInvoke(this);
        }
    }
    public void Sync<T>() where T : Model<T>
    {
        foreach(UpdatePrototype<T> handler in listeners)
        {
            handler.Invoke((T)this);
        }
    }

    public string Name = "Model";
}

public class MyModel : Model<MyModel>
{
    public string Name = "MyModel";
}

public class YourModel : Model<YourModel>
{
    public string Name = "YourModel";
}

void Main()
{
    MyModel mdl = new MyModel();
    mdl.Bind(MyUpdate);
    mdl.Sync<MyModel>();
    mdl.Sync();

    YourModel your = new YourModel();
    your.Bind(YourUpdate);
    your.Sync<YourModel>();
    your.Sync();
}

void MyUpdate(MyModel mdl)
{
    Debug.Log(mdl.Name);
}

void YourUpdate(YourModel mdl)
{
    Debug.Log(mdl.Name);
}
```

}

Comment: `this` is `Model<T>` not `T`

Answer (score 0):

```
        public class Model<T>
        {
            public delegate void UpdatePrototype<S>(S mdl);

            private List<UpdatePrototype<Model<T>>> listeners = new List<UpdatePrototype<Model<T>>>();
            public void Bind(UpdatePrototype<Model<T>> handler)
            {
                listeners.Add(handler);
            }

            public void Sync()
            {
                foreach (UpdatePrototype<Model<T>> handler in listeners)
                {
                    handler(this);
                }
            }

            public virtual string Name
            {
                get
                {
                    return "Model";
                }
            }
        }

        public class MyModel : Model<MyModel>
        {
            public override string Name
            {
                get
                {
                    return "MyModel";
                }
            }
        }

        public class YourModel : Model<YourModel>
        {
            public override string Name
            {
                get
                {
                    return "YourModel";
                }
            }
        }

        void main()
        {
            MyModel mdl = new MyModel();
            mdl.Bind(MyUpdate);
            mdl.Sync();

            YourModel your = new YourModel();
            your.Bind(YourUpdate);
            your.Sync();
        }

        void MyUpdate(Model<MyModel> mdl)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("MY MODEL HANDLER");
            Console.WriteLine(mdl.Name);
        }

        void YourUpdate(Model<YourModel> mdl)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("YOUR MODEL HANDLER");
            Console.WriteLine(mdl.Name);
        }
```

Comment: This might or might not be a solution, but it would certainly be a good idea to post what you changed and why you did it.

Comment: that help me a lot, thanks. actually i just want to explicit the parameter type of each handler and confused with Model<T> and T ...